# Insert into database with a select and an URL ID

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, prepared-statement

When I try to insert data on a table with several foreign keys. This form have an ID on the navigation.

So I created a form where I select values from different tables (linked to the table where I want to insert values) with action in the same page:

```
<form method="post" action="backend_valuechain.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?> 
    <label>Nom du segment</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="segmentname"/> 

    <label>My Select Name</label>
    <select id="select1">
       <?php 
           foreach ($pdo->query($typosegment = 'SELECT ID_SEGMENT_VC_TYPO, SEGMENT_VC_TYPOLOGY FROM segment_vc_typo;') as $row) {
                 echo '<option  name="' . $row['SEGMENT_VC_TYPOLOGY'] . '" value="' .$row['ID_SEGMENT_VC_TYPO'] . '"> ' . $row['SEGMENT_VC_TYPOLOGY'] . '</option>'; } ?>
   </select>
......
```

I have several other select and input text but for making my question easier to read I just take a sample. Once I created my form, I plan to insert the data into the database.

```
<?php
    try{
        $vcNewSegment = "INSERT INTO segment_vc (ID_VC,SEGMENT_VC_NAME,ID_SEGMENT_VC_TYPO) VALUES (:id,:segmentname,:typosegment)";

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($vcNewSegment);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $_GET['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':segmentname', $_REQUEST['segmentname'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':typosegment', $_REQUEST['typosegment'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        echo "OK !";
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        die("ERROR: Could not able to execute $vcNewSegment. " .
            $e->getMessage());
    } 
    unset($pdo);
?>
```

When I insert data through the form, I don't see input inside the table but "NULL" Values are inserted in this table (I removed some columns which are not relevant) :

```
CREATE TABLE `segment_vc` (
  `ID_SEGMENT_VC` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `ID_VC` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ID_SEGMENT_VC_TYPO` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SEGMENT_VC_NAME` varchar(90) DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

ID_SEGMENT_VC is the primary key
ID_VC is a foreign key (it appears in the URL) ..
ID_SEGMENT_TYPO is also a foreign key

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where `$_REQUEST['typosegment']` comes from.

The value of `<select id="select1">` would be obtained by `$_POST['select1']` though.

Comment: It seems that Davids' `$_REQUEST['typosegment']` is your `$_POST['select1']` ;-) Because each select option's value references "ID_SEGMENT_VC_TYPO" field, which is also used in the insert statement in `backend_valuechain.php`.

Comment: it's right : typosegment is the select1...
Changing the REQUEST in POST doesn't change my problem... In fact i don't want to insert the text i put  in the select option but the value i have in the option : <option value="1"> My value</option> .. In thiis case i want to insert "1" as an integer in the table...